# Can't make backup using aptik

Tags: backup

I tried to make a back using both GUI and command line but result of a full backup with Aptik was a folder with less than 50kbs. Need to install fresh Ubuntu

Comment: Size depends on what is being backed up. If only software sources then 50KB should be enough.

Comment: @del-pasand - what is your question, exactly?

Comment: I think was better to ask more clearly. I have installed Wine, couple of other tools. The size of /var/ is more than 700mb but the FULL backup is 50K. I need all softwares, packages and all the downloaded materials to be backed up. any suggestions how to do it ?